# How to find the maximum number in list in list?

Tags: python, list, max

I have the probabilities in list which is again in list , How do I get the maximum number from it , In this case it should return 0.20 number.

```
     [[0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.13
      0.     0.     0.     0.1465 0.01   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.01   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.02   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.03   0.     0.01   0.
      0.     0.01   0.     0.01   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.05   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.01   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.07   0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.04   0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.01   0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.16   0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.03
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.2035 0.     0.     0.05   0.    ]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
max(max(x) for x in my_list)
```

or

```py
max(sum(my_list, []))
```

or

```py
import numpy as np
np.max(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pythonic solution:

```
max_ = max(max(list_))
print(max_)
```

It should give the desired output.

Comment: you are taking 3 maximums, 2 should be enough

Comment: 2 maximums will give you only the sublist that contains the max and not the max itself, try it.

Comment: yes, but as you can see with another solution it can be done with 2 (or 1) maximums

Comment: Yeah, I saw your solution, it seems easy